# Splitting NodeJS (Express API) Project into 2 repositorys

Tags: node.js, express

I have a large Nodejs-Express Project, and I have to add new functionality to my project which is potentially 30+ APIs.

Ideally, I would like to split it into 2 different repositories and modularise it, but I am not sure how to split it up and how will it function deployment-wise.

Is there a way to create some routes on a different repo and keep it modular?

Comment: I would suggest you to check https://github.com/lerna/lerna